# Visual Studio project, local .dll reference backed by Nuget .dll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dll, nuget

I'm working on multiple Visual Studio .Net projects and they all share a Nuget package that I am also developing in tandem. For testing I would like to refer directly to the .dll generated by my Nuget project (without having to pack it up and install it in each of the test projects).

I was wondering if there was someway to indicate in a Visual Studio project that a project should reference a specific .dll in a certain path, however fallback to the proper Nuget package.

In most machines that .dll path will not exist so they'll end up using the Nuget package, but on my machine it would mean I have a direct line to the development version of my .dll.

By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for this example but I would also be interested to know if this is possible in Visual Studio 2015 projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use msbulid condition to check if some file exists:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx

Some samples:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets')" />
```

Or:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="('$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '') and '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.5'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
```

Comment: I'm a little unfamiliar with this. My assumption is that I would put the code proposed into the .csproj files for projects that have the nuget installed. The first tag you proposed includes some targets file, I assume I would have to replace this with the desired debugging .dll? How would I then indicate to use that .dll in-place-of the nuget packaged .dll? EDIT: Your second example seems to do more of what I want, but I'm unfamiliar with where it would be placed in the .csproj and how to indicate the path to a file there. I guess I would modify the condition and replace the reference tags?

Comment: Yes, you would need to find your references and replace them with conditions

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question right you should just be able to add a reference to the .dll that is generated in the bin folder of your project. 
If adding a reference is something you aren't familiar with I can explain how to do this.

Adding a reference:

-Right click the "References" node in your Solution Explorer
-Click "Browse..." in the bottom right-hand corner.
-Navigate to the folder that stores the .dll file.

Now every time you make a change to the .dll and compile it these changes will be automatically reflected in the host program.

Comment: Won't this stop people who do not have a development version of my .dll from building?

Comment: I'm not sure how you distribute your program to users but if you right click on the reference to your .dll and make sure the "Copy Local" setting is set to true this will send a copy of the .dll to your bin folder every time the program is ran in Visual Studio. So when you run your executable outside of VS it will reflect the most recent changes of that .dll.

Comment: Apologies but this answers a different question from what I'm referring to. If I use "copy local" then it will copy the in-development version of the .dll that I've replaced the nuget with. Which I suppose is fine but doesn't provide me with a nuget-backed solution. That is to say that if I commit this code to my repository and someone doesn't have the other solution cloned they will be stuck with a dangling reference when they try to build. The other solution comes closer to what I need.